# How can I generate a pivot table using this data?

Tags: excel

I have this table:

[image]

Is it possible to make a pivot table to present the information like this?:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's possible. As shown in your example, you just need to change the special character "✔️" by the number 1 using "ctrl + f". Then insert a Pivot Table with the data. And finally, create a new column named TOTAL and add the "=sum()" formula to count the items from each row. Something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to move this data from the word doc you are using into an Excel worksheet, in order to generate a pivot table.

[format your data like this in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayjof.jpg)

To start out creating a pivot table, make sure that all rows and columns are selected and record (row) must not be obscure or elusive and must be making sense. Navigate to Insert tab, click PivotTable.

You will reach Create Pivot Table dialog box. Excel fills in data range from first to last selected columns and rows. You can also specify any external data source to be used. Finally choose worksheet to save the pivot table report.

The pivot table should appear. You can then populate this table with data fields which will pop up on the right hand side. Enable the fields you wish to compare in the [pivot table report](https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-create-pivot-table-chart/).